# Error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I am seeing below error when I run my code after deploying to QA Env. This same code was working fine in our eclipse. I have added lombok dependency in POM file. Do we need to install lombok to unix box as well like in eclipse ?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No accessor to set property @org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn(ordering=ASCENDING, forceQuote=false, name=order_number, type=PARTITIONED, value=order_number, ordinal=0)private final java.lang.String test.com.zdc.tmp.persistence.entity.OrderEntity.orderNumber!
    at test.com.zdc.tmp.persistence.entity.OrderEntity_Accessor_u9f29k.setProperty(Unknown Source) ~[periscope-persistence-0.0.1b191.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:313) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperties(MappingCassandraConverter.java:300) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.doReadEntity(MappingCassandraConverter.java:289) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.doReadEntity(MappingCassandraConverter.java:274) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:252) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:248) ~[spring-data-cassandra-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.10.RELEASE]
```

OrderEntity Code.

```
@Table("test")
@Value
@Builder
public class OrderEntity {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "order_number", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    String orderNumber;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Value does not generate setters in lombok. see [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value)

what about using @Data?

Comment: I will try that. Any idea why this same code was running fine in local eclipse ?

Comment: have you changed the version of lombok or spring-data recently?lombok up to v0.11.8 generated `@Wither` methods for each final private field by default in connection with `@Value`, but not anymore and spring-data can utilize these `@Wither` methods to set a final private field. Spring data from version Lovelace (2.1.10.RELEASE) does not use reflection anymore to set final private fields.

Comment: I am using lombok-1.16.22.jar